# Android smartphone providing reasonable touch pressure measures

Tags: android, touchscreen

I'm interested in getting the pressure of the touch on smartphones. As far as I know there are no current available smartphones with built in touch pressure sensors (force touch). The only devices I know are the Huawei Mate S (force touch version) which is no more available.

The touch pressure can also be inferred through the contact area. I have also read that some of the devices are just returning 1 using event.getPressure (). This is also true for Galaxy Note 4 (I have this phone).

Is there a list of smartphones which provide reasonable values for event.getPressure()?